# On the Self Language, how do we run code on its VM?

Tags: self, selflanguage

If Self is installed on Ubuntu using the file on http://selflanguage.org/, then we can use

```
$ Self
Self Virtual Machine Version 4.1.13, Sat 20 Feb 10 22:39:48 Linux
Copyright 1989-2003: The Self Group (type _Credits for credits)

for I386:  LogVMMessages = true
for I386:  PrintScriptName  = true
for I386:  Inline = true
for I386:  SICDeferUncommonBranches = false (not implemented)
for I386:  SICReplaceOnStack = false (not implemented)
for I386:  SaveOutgoingArgumentsOfPatchedFrames = true
```

However, some simple lines cannot be run:

```
VM# 'Hello, World!' print.
A lookup error happened while sending the message
    print
to
    'Hello, World!'.
Subsequently, the lookup error message
    undefinedSelector:Receiver:Type:Delegatee:MethodHolder:Arguments:
was sent to
    <0>,
and was also not understood, causing the process to be aborted by the Self VM.

#0 (<error>:1): print = ( | self* = 'Hello, World!'. delegatee = nil. selector = 'print'. | 
"undefined selector error;
this method was automatically generated by the VM."
 )


#1 (<stdin>:1): <top level expr> = ( | self* = lobby. | 'Hello, World!' print )
```

Or another one to try out the slots:

```
VM# _AddSlots: (| vehicle <- (|parent* = traits clonable|) |).
A lookup error happened while sending the message
    traits
to
    lobby.
Subsequently, the lookup error message
    undefinedSelector:Receiver:Type:Delegatee:MethodHolder:Arguments:
was sent to
    <0>,
and was also not understood, causing the process to be aborted by the Self VM.

#0 (<error>:1): traits = ( | self* = lobby. delegatee = nil. selector = 'traits'. | 
"undefined selector error;
this method was automatically generated by the VM."
 )


#1 (<stdin>:1): <top level expr> = ( | self* = lobby. | traits clonable )


                             ^
Self VM error: couldn't construct object literal on line 1, character 30
               ^
Self VM error: couldn't construct object literal on line 1, character 16
VM#
```

Does someone know how to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you encounter is the most basic form of self that is out there.

The VM by itself only knows very little messages. They include all primitives
and a few messages such as `bootstrap`.

If you try it, things like `_Quit` or `'some/path/to/self/script' _RunScript` 
will work, as these are primitives that are always available.

If you want an working environment, you have to either

- load a snapshot by starting the VM with the `-s` option:

  ```
  Self -s mySnapshot.snap
  ```

  You can find a snapshot on the self homepage.
- Run a world building script. For that, you need the `objects` directory
  that comes with self. If you can't find it, use the one from the [github page](https://github.com/russellallen/self). Then, change your working directory to the `objects` directory and run the world builder script.

  ```
  cd $PATH_TO_OBJECTS/objects
  Self -f worldBuilder.self
  ```

  Alternatively, point the `SELF_WORKING_DIR` environment variable to the directory *containing* the `objects` directory and run the sctipt.

  ```
  SELF_WORKING_DIR=$PATH_TO_OBJECTS Self -f s$PATH_TO_OBJECTS/worldBuilder.self
  ```

This bootstraps a self world, where every known message should be understood.

PS:  Surely, you can also run the word builder script from within the running VM: `'/path/to/dir/with/objects/worldBuilder.self' _RunScript'`. But make sure that SELF_WORKING_DIR is set.